# How do I pass layout false inside respond_to block in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, respond-to

I'm trying to figure out how to make this work. Here is my code, which is not working right now:

```
  respond_with(@addresses) do |format|
    format.json {render :json=>@addresses, :layout=>false}
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:layout` parameter shouldn't be necessary when you're rendering json, xml, etc.